# How can I force gdrive to download a folder as zipped file?

Tags: google-drive

Ubuntu version: `14.04.5 LTS`.

> gdrive is a command line utility for interacting with Google Drive.

I have initialized `gdrive` (https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) with a specific user. As example `gdrive about` returns its information.

The way we can download a uploaded folder as follows:

```
gdrive [global] download [options] <fileId>
```

For more information please type: `gdrive help download`.

I want to download a folder through using `gdrive download` as zipped. Is there any way to force downloading a folder as zipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current iteration of `gdrive`, you can't.  The feature wasn't written or developed into it.

There have been several requests (like [this one](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/issues/344)) for the functionality requested to be added, but they haven't had any action from the developer (yet).

(And something to note: the developer of `gdrive` hasn't made any changes since September of 2017, so it's possible this is an 'abandoned' project, and won't get further development; this is, however, not able to be easily determined)

Comment: I guess my alternative option might be: zip a folder as `.zi`p or `.tar.gz` and store it under a folder. Later if a folder is shared with another user, they can upload file into it instead of updating/overwriting it. @Thomas Ward♦